# 500 (Internal Server Error) when making an HTTP POST call

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following Angular 8 application that calls a WebAPI # controller.

```cs
login(formData) {
    return this.http.post(this.BaseURI + '/ApplicationUser/Login', formData);
}
```

When running this I get a 500 error. Any suggestions on why?

Comment: It's not enough information to answer on your question. [500 error](https://www.westhost.com/knowledgebase/display/WES/What+Is+A+500+error) usually means there is something wrong on the server side. So just check if `this.BaseURI + '/ApplicationUser/Login'` URL exists, if `this.BaseURI` server is up and running.

Comment: Please post the log of your server here. If you are not responsible for your server, please tell the issue with your server manager. Mostly it was not an issue about angular.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not complete to answer.

But the 500 error means internal server error that mean there is something wrong at server end (API end).